# Cannot run python after update macOS to Monterey

Tags: python, macos-monterey

The terminal shows these errors after I updated my MacBook and run a python program. How can I fix it?

```
dyld[4136]: dyld cache '/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
dyld[4136]: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Try updating Python to the latest version. 3.6 may not work with Monterey.

Comment: The file works well in the terminal, but shows above errors in the terminal in VSCode. I am confused.

Comment: I just installed the latest version. Seems I should work on the configuration of VSCode now.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Having the same issue `CoreFoundation` is indeed missing from the shown path.. But should it be elsewhere? Very annoying

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update your Python version as well as other packages installed that rely on Python.
I'd recommend using HomeBrew and running `brew upgrade python` or `brew upgrade`
You might also need to update your xcode command line tools by running `xcode-select --install` prior to running `brew upgrade`.